# NodeJS: is it better to inject dependencies as function parameters or expose using module.exports?

Tags: node.js, web-applications, express, dependency-injection, circular-dependency

I have a web app and I am currently passing dependencies using parameters when I invoke the require(); like so...

```
// Main app.js file

var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
//config file for dev/production settings
var config = require('./config/');

//Set up App object etc.
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
//Set up socket.io server & export as an app.publicMethod
var io = module.exports.io = require('socket.io')(http);
//Time Formatter exported so Jade can access
app.locals.moment = require('moment');

//Set up database using mongoose
var models = module.exports.models = require('./config/mongoose');

//Setup Operations (formerly controllers)
var operations = require('./controller')(app, models, io);

//Set up Routes (views & api)
var routes = require('./routes')(app, models, io, operations);

//Fire it up
var port = process.env.PORT || config.port;

http.listen(port, function() {
console.log('Started on port '+port);
  //Start any operations that need to wait for the server to start
  //operations.start();
});
```

Specifically this line

```
//Set up Routes (views & api)
var routes = require('./routes')(app, models, io, operations);
```

I recently needed to call the models from another independent script. So I put in this line that exposes a public method and allows me to call this file from the other script.

```
//Set up database using mongoose
var models = module.exports.models = require('./config/mongoose');
```

I don't like mixing these techniques as it could quickly become confusing and create circular dependencies as the app continues to develop. Which is the best way to do it? Is there a better way to pass parameters between my scripts?

Comment: A module should `require()` in by itself the things that it needs to make it more modular and easier to use in other projects.  If you have singletons (e.g. initialized objects - not just require handles) that need to be shared, then you can use either the push or pull model of sharing.

Comment: Thankyou, do you have a link to somewhere I could read more on this?

Answer (score 1):

I found my own answer in the D of [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29) from object oriented principles.

"[Dependency Inversion Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle)"

First I had to realise that the node philosophy is modular by nature. Everything should always have the possibility of being turned into a module that could be used in an even bigger project.

When I kept that principle in mind I realised that we have a simple set of parent children relationships. Every script file is either a parent of child dependencies, or a child of a parent script. When a parent file such as the app.js calls its children files it uses `require('./routes');` There should never be a situation such that the app as a parent object is exported and included in a child script. Because that leaves what I like to call a 'voodoo link' that is a connection which is obscure to any incoming programmer trying to clean up my code. There would be a danger of circular dependencies or worse.

So I have banned `module.exports` from my app file until such a time as my entire project could be packaged up and turned into a module dependency of an even larger architecture. This stops the possibility of a child of app.js calling its parent as a dependency.

Instead when I require a child script I can pass parameters to it using dependency injection like so `var routes = require('./routes')(models, io);`
This allows the child scripts to maintain their independence by presenting a limited set of variables with which to perform its operations.

There are occasions when I do need to require scripts into the child scripts. I like to think of this as niece or nephew scripting. That is that a script such as 'routes.js' calls a module dependency of the entire project. But it is never something being manipulated directly in the 'app.js' parent of the project that should instead be injected as a dependency as above.

```
//Child dependency of app.js (e.g. routes)
var twitter = require('twitter-npm-module');
module.exports = function (models, io) {
    ...
    twitter.scrape('some keyword');
};
```

As to my final problem which was that I wished to call the models from another script not within my normal parent/child tree structure. There was three options.

1. Turn my entire app into a dependency of this new script.
2. Turn the new script into a child of the app.js and injects dependencies using the technique above.
3. Create a completely separate module that would run as a separate process and pass messages between the two using some sort of queue system.

I am trying out option 3 with rabbitmq.